# How to replace space by character in a specific column?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a text file (tab delimited) where I want to replace a 'space' in column # 1750960 with a character '0'. How to do this?

Comment: By column do you mean the n-th character of a line when n is the number you posted?

Comment: Can you show some sample input?

Comment: Include what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact talking about the 1750960-th character on a line this is a nifty way to go about it

```
echo $YOUR_LINE | sed 's|\(.\{1750959\}\).|\10|'
```

the`\(` and `\)' take whatever is matched inside them and relates it back to`\1` to be used in the replacement.

I hope this helps